# Why does spark-shell --master yarn-client fail with "UnknownHostException: Invalid host name"?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, apache-spark-1.6

This is Spark **1.6.1**.

When I do below at `spark/bin`

```
$ ./spark-shell --master yarn-client
```

I get the following error.

[image]

I checked hostname at `/etc/hosts` and also in Hadoop but they are assigned as same hostname. Any idea?

Comment: What's your `yarn-site.xml` and other Hadoop config files? What's the Spark version?

Comment: yarn-site.xml configuration part looks like:

<property><name>yarn.nodemanager.auxservices.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name><value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.shuffleHandler</value>
</property>

<property><name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name> <value>localhost:8025</value></property>

<property><name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
<value>localhost:8030</value></property>

<property><name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
<value>master:8035</value></property>

Comment: hdfs-site.xml configuration part looks like:
<property>
     27 <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
     28 <value>file:/home/bohyun/data/hadoop/dfs/name</value>
     29 <final>true</final> </property>
     30 <property>
     31 <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
     32 <value>file:/home/bohyun/data/hadoop/dfs/data</value>
     33 <final>true</final> </property>
     34 <property> <name>dfs.permissions</name> <value>false</value>
     35 </property>

Comment: Why do have `yarn.resourcemanager.address` value alone set to `master` host whereas it is `localhost` in other properties? And do you have an entry for `master` in `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: Can you do `ping master` from the machine where you execute `spark-shell`?

Comment: Can you add `yarn-site.xml` to the question?

Comment: Thank you @franklinsijo & Jacek Laskowski.
I went through all xml files as you mentioned and edited paths all over again and it works! Thank you so much for your help!